# In/inside/within two minutes

Tags: prepositions, difference

This sentence uses *inside* with time. What is the difference between *in two minutes* and *within two minutes*?

> Brentford led **inside two minutes**. Mads Roerslev whips a perfect low cross in from the right, and Keane Lewis-Potter cushions a volley home.

Comment: The implied context is "with less than two minutes remaining".  Within two minutes of the end.  In this instance, time is counting *down*, the seconds "ticking away".

Comment: You need to use a dictionary before posting.

Comment: @TimR  I disagree.  I'd say it is less that two minutes from the start.

Comment: @JamesK - Yes.  _Keane Lewis-Potter's second strike of the Premier League season opens the scoring for Brentford inside the opening 90 seconds_ also _Brentford had led inside two minutes through Lewis-Potter's second goal of the season, the forward diverting Mads Roerslev's cross into the net at full stretch after a quick break. Palace levelled after 14 minutes through Olise,_ 2 minutes is before 14 minutes. But in the end... Palace 3 Brentford 1

Comment: @JamesK: I don't know the actual game in question , but **inside two minutes** could refer to either the start or the end of a game, after less than two minutes of play have elapsed or when less than two minutes remain.  The reference point is contextual.

Comment: Here's an example of less than two minutes remaining: https://www.palmbeachpost.com/story/sports/2023/11/28/alessia-saia-powers-spanish-river-girls-soccer-past-olympic-heights/71715601007/

Comment: That example is "inside two minutes remaining"  the word remaining makes a difference.  The OP's example is pretty clearly "two minutes from the start.

Comment: (one reason for that is that you don't know how many minutes are actually remaining because "injury time" will be added, which may add 5-10 minutes to the match)

Comment: @JamesK - my comments above were about the same match that the OP quoted a Tweet about, namely Brentford vs Crystal Palace at Selhurst Park on 30 Dec 2023.

Comment: Dear Nyambek - you must get in the habit of saying where you get your quotes from.

Comment: @jamesK  I could find other examples without "remaining".  In American football there's a two-minute warning when the game is down to the final two-minutes of each half -- which is was why my first thought was that the goal described in the question was scored in the final minutes of the game. "all plays are automatically reviewable *inside two minutes*" https://sites.google.com/view/plaayfaq/cold-snap-football

Comment: Perhaps there is a dialect issue here then.

Comment: @JamesK There's no dialect issue here since "[a team, here Brentford] led inside two minutes" can only mean: as of two minutes when they started to play (football/soccer). This is not American football and "reviewing plays". As you say above: two minutes from the start of playing.

Answer (score 0):

inside

Merriam Webster:

2
: WITHIN
*inside an hour*

Cambridge Dictionary: AmE and BrE

if you do something or something happens inside (of) a particular time or limit, you do it or it happens in less than that amount of time:
The work should be finished *inside a week.*

Comment: To clarify, do you understand this as "2 minutes from the end" or "2 minutes from the start" (see comments on the question)

Comment: @JamesK They are leading within two minutes as of some time period. The beginning of the game or the second half.

Comment: The question did not address which end is timed, only the difference of prepositions, which this answer answers.

Answer (score -2):

I will answer the question based on American usage, which, unlike British usage, would normally require singular verbs with collective subjects.

> Brentford leads for two minutes.

This means that the time Brentford has been leading totals about two minutes.  The strong default understanding is that the speaker is talking about the specific continuous two-minute period that includes and ends with the moment of speaking.

> Brentford leads in two minutes.

This would be a strange sentence but appears to assert as already established that Brentford will be leading after a two-minute period has elapsed.

Out of context, "in two minutes" is ambiguous and is the default expression for two different meanings.  It can mean (1) that an activity or process covers about a two-minute period, or (2) that something will not take place until after about a two-minute period has elapsed.  The second usage is probably more common and so assumed to be the meaning unless something else indicates that the first meaning is meant.

The first meaning is usually possible only for verbs and verb phrases that describe an end point for the period described or a completion at the end of that time period; however, it is possible to use "in" for this meaning if the preposition "in" refers to a definite time period, perhaps as an analogy with physical location.  As a result, you can say:

> Brentford leads in the final two minutes of the game.

This locates the time of Brentford's lead somewhere in the final two minutes of the game.

Since "Brentford leads" does not describe and endpoint and "two minutes" does not describe a specific "location" in time, "in two minutes" will be understood to mean "after a two-minute period has elapsed."  Again, this would be quite an  odd thing to assert in this case.

> (*)Brentford leads within two minutes.

This would normally mean that Brentford leads within the last two minutes of the game; however, many speakers would find this phrasing odd.

The expression "within two minutes" has the same meaning and same restrictions as the first meaning of "in two minutes," except that it expresses the maximum limits of the activity rather than the approximate length.  It means "in less than two minutes."

Normally, you cannot use a phrase like "within two minutes" for a verb that doesn't describe an endpoint.  You normally cannot say: *"Our team led within two minutes"; however, since use of the word "within" implies a specific outer limit by itself, you might reinterpret "two minutes" to mean "the final two minutes of the game."

> Brentford leads inside two minutes.

This means Brentford is leading with less than two minutes left in the game and is normal language for sports commentary.

This temporal use of "inside" has exactly the same rules as "within"; however, its connotation is more about being on one side of a boundary than about being less than some maximum period.  As a result, it is very easy to understand that "two minutes" expresses that boundary and refers to the two-minute mark as the clock winds down to the end of the game.

The particular sentence has a distinct flavor of informal sports commentary and might not be readily understandable by those unfamiliar with timed sports.

Comment: It wasn't about anything else than the expression: inside. Why you would bother with the collective noun in AmE and BrE is beyond me here.

Comment: I mentioned that because I had to change the quote.